How to insert the "Copy to clipboard" icon in an r markdown document
I want to insert the Copy to clipboard icon in my chunks and instead of a complicated description just see the image, which is a screenshot of chapter 3.1 of the R Markdown Cookbook.
My code (with the missing lines of code to get that icon and tooltip like in the image):
---
title: "First R Markdown Document"
author: "My name"
date: "Last edited: `r format(Sys.time(), '%d.%m.%Y')`"
output: html_document
---

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents.

You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r, echo=TRUE}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r, echo=TRUE}
plot(cars)
```

All I found is using the package klippy - but that's an other approach (or?!).
Thanks a lot in advance!


What is the problem with klippy? I took a look at the doc and it seems appropriate.

@StéphaneLaurent It's not that nice formatted like that one in the screenshot - and I know this complaining on a high level... And I was curious how to solve that.

It seems that this particular button is only available with the bookdown::gitbook() format (or natively with Quarto). So you need :
install.packages("bookdown"), then :
---
title: "First R Markdown Document"
author: "My name"
date: "Last edited: `r format(Sys.time(), '%d.%m.%Y')`"
output: bookdown::gitbook
---
  
This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents.

You can embed an R code chunk like this:
  
```{r, echo=TRUE}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:
  
```{r, echo=TRUE}
plot(cars)
```


I found a package I have used in the past, link here. Called Klippy I was only able to get the clipboard functionality to work with specific markdown options where it displays for all chuncks, maybe you can find a way to control the output more.
You can use the klippy package, need devtools installed to pull it from github
---
title: "stackoverlfow"
author: "John Doe"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

# loading libraries
```{r klippy, include=TRUE}
klippy::klippy()
library(ggplot2)
```

# copy the code below
```{r klippy2, include=TRUE, warning=FALSE}
qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = iris)
```


